# Check if actor system has finished its work

Tags: scala, akka

I have written an Akka-based automaton which can accept roman numbers from 1 to 20. The automaton works fine, but after handling the complete input I want to shutdown the system.

Because I do not know when the automaton finishes I do not know when to send the stop signal. This results in the problem, that the system is halted too early and the automaton can not finish its tasks. What is the best way to check if there are tasks in the actor system which are not yet completed?

The automaton:

```
import akka.actor.{Props, ActorSystem, ActorRef, Actor}

object RomanNumberAcceptor extends App {

  val allLegalNumbers = List("I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X",
    "XI", "XII", "XIII", "XIV", "XV", "XVI", "XVII", "XVIII", "XIX", "XX"
  )

  val someWrongNumbers = List("IXX", "VV", "VX", "IIII", "IVV", "XXX", "XXI", "XXV", "IIX", "IIIV")

  for (number <- allLegalNumbers)
    State testNumber number

  for (number <- someWrongNumbers)
    State testNumber number

  // this stop signal is too early
  State.stop()
}

case class WordData(fullWord: String, remainder: String)

object State {
  val ErrorStateId: Int = -1

  private val data = Map(
    0 -> (Map('I' -> 1, 'V' -> 5, 'X' -> 10), false),
    1 -> (Map('I' -> 2, 'V' -> 4, 'X' -> 9), true),
    2 -> (Map('I' -> 3, 'V' -> ErrorStateId, 'X' -> ErrorStateId), true),
    3 -> (Map('I' -> ErrorStateId, 'V' -> ErrorStateId, 'X' -> ErrorStateId), true),
    4 -> (Map('I' -> ErrorStateId, 'V' -> ErrorStateId, 'X' -> ErrorStateId), true),
    5 -> (Map('I' -> 6, 'V' -> ErrorStateId, 'X' -> ErrorStateId), true),
    6 -> (Map('I' -> 2, 'V' -> ErrorStateId, 'X' -> ErrorStateId), true),
    9 -> (Map('I' -> ErrorStateId, 'V' -> ErrorStateId, 'X' -> ErrorStateId), true),
    10 -> (Map('I' -> 1, 'V' -> 5, 'X' -> 20), true),
    20 -> (Map('I' -> ErrorStateId, 'V' -> ErrorStateId, 'X' -> ErrorStateId), true),
    ErrorStateId -> (Map.empty[Char, Int], false)
  )

  val system = ActorSystem("RomanNumberAcceptor")

  val states: Map[Int, ActorRef] =
    for ((id, (map, accepted)) <- State.data)
      yield id -> system.actorOf(Props(State(id, map, accepted)), name = "s"+id)

  def testNumber(s: String) {
    states(0) ! WordData(s, s)
  }

  def stop() {
    for (a <- states.values)
      system stop a
    system.shutdown()
  }
}

case class State(id: Int, transMap: Map[Char, Int], accepted: Boolean) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case WordData(fullWord, _) if `id` == State.ErrorStateId =>
      println("Error: "+fullWord)
    case WordData(fullWord, remainder) if remainder.isEmpty =>
      println((if (accepted) "Success: " else "Error: ") + fullWord)
    case WordData(fullword, remainder) =>
      // maybe some heavy operation here
      (0 to 1e4.toInt).sum

      val nextAktor = transMap(remainder.head)
      State.states(nextAktor) ! WordData(fullword, remainder.tail)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

(The following assumes the non-Akka actors of Scala. See the edit below for how to adjust this to work with Akka)

There are two possible answers to this in my opinion:

1. It doesn't make sense. By design, each of your state actors is not *finished* as such, because it could still take more input words at any time and is just waiting for them. What is finished is your code that sends the words to be checked.
2. Although you do not seem to return any useful values for the `WordData` message, you can still wait for the return value. You should in particular look at the usage of the `!!` and `!?` operators. By chaining them over the different actors you could then wait for them to have processed the word. Be careful though with `!?`, as re-entrant states could lead to deadlocks.

Instead, I'd suggest that you define a `Boolean` answer for the `WordData` message that tells you whether the word was accepted or not. You can then use `!!` to retrieve a future (depending on another future, which depends on another future, and so on for the word's length) and the `testNumber` method could then block to retrieve the acceptance value. If you want to test multiple words in parallel, you could also have `testNumber` return the `Future` itself, and block on all these futures in the `App` object before calling `stop`.

In short: You should lookup the `!!` operator for actors together with the `Future` type.

**Edit:** Sorry for the confusion. This has indeed changed with Akka 2, as drexin pointed out in the comment. See the [Akka documentation of Futures](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/futures.html) for how to send a message such that a future is retrieved.

As for retrieving only `None`: Of course, the actors will have to return a meaningful value of some kind (like the `Boolean` proposed above). See the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/actors.html#Reply_to_messages) again on how to send replies from an actor (basically, `sender ! true`). Note that of course, only the base cases can return `true` or `false`. When you call another actor, you will again get a future and to avoid deadlocks you will have to return that directly.

Hence, on the calling side you will have to successively await these futures, i.e. wait for the outermost future to evaluate to another future. Then wait for this future, and so on, until you retrieve a non-future boolean result value.

The problem with calling the next actor from within your actor and returning the evaluation of the corresponding future (instead of the future itself), means that the calling actor will be blocked. So this would cause the same deadlock behavior as traditional Scala actors would have when using blocking `!?` calls.

Comment: The OP is obviously using Akka 2.x which has no !! or !? methods. In Akka 2.x you retrieve a Future by importing `akka.pattern.ask` and use either `ask` or `?`.

Comment: @drexin: I tried to use Future, but I get only None as result. Inside of State I did a `sender ! msg`. I think this does not work because sender is another State actor and not the Future. How to response to the Future?

Comment: No, this is totally correct. I assume you tried to call `future.value`? This will return None as long as the future is not completed. Try `onComplete` or `pipeTo` instead. You should also read http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/futures.html